# Join two mysql tables in a query?

Tags: php, mysql, join

My aim is to prepare a newsletter which sends all my users an email when they haven't logged in for longer than two weeks.

To accomplish this, I need to "join" (I think) the last logged in date (from myMembers table) and their preference in receiving emails or not (from accountOptions table).

myMembers

===============
id    last_logged_date
1                 date
2                date

accountOptions

===============
id uid notification1
1       1        yes   
2          2            no

What is the query I need to use here to extract th?

Comment: A `JOIN` query, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html - You're not talking about a specific problem that you've run into, you're just asking for the general documentation. Please check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) which questions to ask. A general rule of thumb is that you provide code about what you did. You didn't with your question.

Comment: to accomplish join here you need the reference of uid in myMembers table. Do you have any relation between myMembers and accountoptions table?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from myMembers m, accountOptions o
where u.notification='yes' AND m.id = o.uid 
AND AND DATEDIFF(Now(), m.last_logged_date) > 14
```

DateDiff(date1, date2) returns the difference between these two dates in days.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 0):

assuming id as the reference

```
select aO.id, aO.uid, m.last_logged_date from accountOptions aO inner join myMembers m on 
aO.id = m.id where  m.last_logged_date <= DATEDIFF(Now(), m.last_logged_date) > 14
and notification1 = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to join 2 tables

```
SELECT * 
  FROM myMembers,accountOptions 
 WHERE myMembers.id = accountOptions.uid 
   AND id=1;
```

This will return the exact result.

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT myMembers.last_logged_date, accountOptions.notification1
FROM myMembers
INNER JOIN accountOptions
ON myMembers.P_Id=accountOptions.uid
ORDER BY myMembers.id**